# python get parse option from raw_input

Tags: python

How can I use parser options in `raw_input`.
I'll give an example:

```
import optparse
import win32ui 
a = raw_input('Message box')
parser = optparse.OptionsParser()
parser.add_options('-t', dest='title', type='string')
parser.add_options('-m', dest='message', type='string')
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
title = options.title
message = options.message
win32ui.MessageBox(message, title, 0)
```

When I enter for example `-t hello -m how are you`, I want a message box to appear with these options.

How can I solve this please and thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To start with, it's best to not use `optparse` as this is now a deprecated module, and you should prefer `argparse` instead.

By default argparse will parse the command-line input 
 (`sys.argv[1:]`) - however you can pass it a list of variables to parse instead, e.g.:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.parse_args(["-t hello -m how are you"])
```

So in your specific case you can do:

```
(options, args) = parser.parse_args([a])
```

Of course if you have to use `optparse` then it's almost the same:

```
import optparse
parser = optparse.OptionParser()
(options, args) = parser.parse_args([a])
```

Comment: hi can you give an other example  or fix my above example to understand  better and thank you

Comment: Edited to add using your `raw_input` variable `a`

Comment: i find this solution but still needs a good way to use only one raw_input not 2 input

Comment: import optparse
from win32ui import MessageBox
parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option('-t', dest='title', type='string', help='Title of message')
parser.add_option('-m', dest='msg', type='string', help='Message to send')
c = raw_input('send msg')
d = raw_input('send msg')
(options, args) = parser.parse_args([c, d])

title = options.title
msg = options.msg
#print title
MessageBox(msg, title, 0)

Comment: please can you fix this to  use only one raw_input not two

Comment: when i use one raw_input -m doesnt work , None : TypeError: None is not a valid string in this context

Comment: import optparse
from win32ui import MessageBox
parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option('-t', dest='title', type='string', help='Title of message')
parser.add_option('-m', dest='msg', type='string', help='Message to send')
c = raw_input('send msg')

(options, args) = parser.parse_args([c])

title = options.title
msg = options.msg

MessageBox(msg, title, 0)

Comment: gives me this error : python execute.py
send msg-t Greeting -m hello match
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "execute.py", line 13, in <module>
    MessageBox(msg, title, 0)
TypeError: None is not a valid string in this context

Comment: I can't easily read or parse any of that code - please add any changes to the original question, or if it's different enough start a new question - thanks.

Comment: this is my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48431642/python-argparse-get-argument-from-input-raw-input