# python, argparse get argument from input- raw_input

Tags: python, argparse, raw-input

I need help with this issue, I want to take an argument from user input using `argparse` save it to a variable and print out the result

Example: 
**Message to send**:

> -t Greeting -m hello guys how are you

**prints out**:

> greeting hello guys how are you

this is my code:

```
import argparse, shlex
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser() 
parser.add_argument('-t', action='store', dest='title')
parser.add_argument('-m', action='store', dest='msg')
command = raw_input('message to send')

args = parser.parse_args(shlex.split(command)) 
title = args.title
msg = args.msg
print title, msg
```

when you enter, `-t hi -m hello`, it works fine but when you enter more then one word, it doesn't work.  Why?

Comment: it should work if you quote the string after '-m': `-t hi -m "hello blah blah"`

Comment: @cowbert That sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use [click](http://click.pocoo.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, when you declare a command line switch via the **add_argument** method, python considers that only the next world/value should be stored inside the resulting variable. That is why the following works fine:

```
-t hello -m world
```

While the following:

```
-t greetings -m hello world
```

returns something like:

```
greetings hello
```

Using [**nargs**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#nargs), you can tell python how many values should be stored in the final variable.
For example, in your code if you declare your command line switches as:

```
parser.add_argument('-t', action='store', dest='title', nargs='*', type=str, required=True)
parser.add_argument('-m', action='store', dest='msg', nargs='*', type=str, required=True)
```

Python knows that all values following the **-t** switch should be stored in a list called **title**. The same goes for the **-m** switch and the **msg** variable.
Here I also added the **type** and **required** arguments to indicate what type of value is expected and that both switches have to be present in the command line.

---

Fixing your entire script so far:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser() 
parser.add_argument('-t', action='store', dest='title', nargs='*', type=str, required=True)
parser.add_argument('-m', action='store', dest='msg', nargs='*', type=str, required=True)

args = parser.parse_args()
print(" ".join(args.title), " ".join(args.msg))
```

All you have to do is call your script as follow:

```
python3 your_script.py -t greetings -m hello world
```

This should print:

```
greetings hello world
```

as a result.

Comment: hi  @davinellulinvega can you please explane more or fix my code above? and thanks

Comment: Edited my answer with both explanation and code correction. Hope it helps.

Comment: The normal way of handling this is for the caller to quote the input. I have to downvote, I'm afraid.

Comment: @jpmc26: I am not complaining for your downvote here, but I wish to know on what (docs, standard practise, ...) you based your judgement of this not being the "normal way"? Thanks in advance for clarifying this point.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options here. Either quote the argument with spaces like so:

`-t Hi -m "Hello word1 word2"`

or

use [davinellulinvega's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48431773/2718295). To get back the entire string with `nargs='*'`, you'd have to:

```
parser.add_argument('-t', action='store', dest='title', nargs='*')
parser.add_argument('-m', action='store', dest='msg', nargs='*')

....

title = ' '.join(args.title)
msg = ' '.join(args.msg)
```

Comment: Thank you guys you really help me@davinellulinvega @cowbert

Comment: While the positional argument note is important, these arguments aren't positional, they're "optional arguments".

Comment: Quoting is absolutely the standard solution here; users of command lines tools will *expect* to need to do so. I wouldn't even mention the `nargs` bit.